# no module named subprocess in python 2.4.3

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, python-2.4

We have built an linux based application with GUI using python.

While testing, i tried to import subprocess module using python 2.4.1 on FC4, its working.

but on our client's system, they are having python 2.4.3, when i try to import subprocess module, its giving error:

```
 import error: no module named subprocess
```

Our application will not run without subprocess module.

we are working on different linux flavors.

what could be the reason for not having subprocess module in python 2.4.3, when it is available with python 2.4.1?

and what is the solution on this?

Comment: subprocess is not unavailable in python 2.4.3. Is the file present in the python lib directory?

Comment: @rohanwadnerkar I almost hear sound of your wooden keyword - what an old version. But anyway, can you tell us what platforms you are trying to run it on? This sounds important. What is FC4?

Comment: Maybe subprocess was never installed on your server (have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess.run), try (sudo) pip install subprocess.run , if you have installed the python packagemanagement system pip.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Fedora Core, up to version 6 it was the official name. I dunno but IMO there is no good excuse for having outdated packages on system (at least not for over a year). I wonder if their security-related packages are also that old.

Comment: Fedora Core 4 was released in 2005 and got EOL`ed in 2006! You should seriously consider updating your system.